# Unable to connect Pixel Phone to TP Link WiFi extender

Tags: wi-fi

Please bear with me because I have very limited technical knowledge.
I have successfully installed a TP Link WiFi range extender and my iPad connects to it fine. My Pixel phone detects the extender but will not connect to it. When I try to manually select the extender it gets as far as saying Authenticating but then just goes back to showing it is a saved network in my list.
What can I do, in really simple terms,to ensure my Pixel connects to the TP Link extender?
Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the range extender use the same Wifi name (SSID) and password as the main WiFi? Please edit your question and add the exact product name of the "TP Link WiFi range extender".

Comment: typo in password, try again